# How to loop through variables and assign a value of 1 based on multiple substr values at given character locations?

Tags: r, string, loops, substring

I'm moving from SAS to R and i'm trying to convert the following code from SAS to R:

```
data Drug_inj;
set initial;
array odiag(25) odiag1-odiag25;
do i = 1 to 25;
if substrn(odiag(i), 1,3) = 'T36' and (substrn(odiag(i), 6,1) = '1') then total_drug = 1;
if substrn(odiag(i), 1,3) = 'T37' and (substrn(odiag(i), 6,1) = '1') then total_drug = 1;
if substrn(odiag(i), 1,3) = 'T38' and (substrn(odiag(i), 6,1) = '1') then total_drug = 1;
if substrn(odiag(i), 1,3) = 'T39' and (substrn(odiag(i), 6,1) = '1') then total_drug = 1;
if substrn(odiag(i), 1,2) = 'T4'  and (substrn(odiag(i), 6,1) = '1') then total_drug = 1;
if substrn(odiag(i), 1,3) = 'T50' and (substrn(odiag(i), 6,1) = '1') then total_drug = 1;
if substrn(odiag(i), 1,4) = 'T369' == 1 then total_drug = 1;
end;
```

Just like the SAS code, I want the R code to look at the variables "odiag1" through "odiag25" in turn and give the variable "total_drug" a value of "1" on each row where conditions are met. Specifically conditions where the first 3 characters of the string start with "T36" through "T50" and the 6th character is equal to "1".

so far, I've figured that one of the easiest ways to do a loop in R is by creating a list

```
my_list <- list("odiag1" "odiag2" "odiag3" "odiag4" etc. "odiag25")

for i in length(my_list))
{

Drug_inj$total_drug = ifelse(substr(Drug_inj$i, 1,3 == "T36") & substr(Drug_inj$i, 6,1 == "1")) == 1
                      ifelse(substr(Drug_inj$i, 1,3 == "T37") & substr(Drug_inj$i, 6,1 == "1")) == 1
                      ifelse(substr(Drug_inj$i, 1,3 == "T38") & substr(Drug_inj$i, 6,1 == "1")) == 1
                      ifelse(substr(Drug_inj$i, 1,3 == "T39") & substr(Drug_inj$i, 6,1 == "1")) == 1
                      ifelse(substr(Drug_inj$i, 1,2 == "T4") & substr(Drug_inj$i, 6,1 == "1")) == 1
                      ifelse(substr(Drug_inj$i, 1,3 == "T50") & substr(Drug_inj$i, 6,1 == "1")) == 1
                      ifelse(substr(Drug_inj$i, 1,4 == "T369")) == 1}
```

I'm getting this error
"
Error in substr(pdd_master$i, 1, 3 == "T36") & substr(pdd_master$i, 6,  :
operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
"

The code I'm using is modified from some code a coworker gave me. Unfortunately, their codes only need the first 3 or 4 characters, so they used the following code.

```
pdd_master<- pdd_master %>% 
  unite(all_causes, odiag1, odiag2, odiag3, odiag4, odiag5, odiag6, odiag7,
        odiag8, odiag9, odiag10, odiag11, odiag12, odiag13, odiag14, odiag15, odiag16,
        odiag17, odiag18, odiag19, odiag20, odiag21, odiag22, odiag23, odiag24, 
        odiag25 sep = " ", remove = FALSE)

pdd_master$total_drug_unint = ifelse(str_detect(pdd_master$all_causes, "T36")==T,1,                                         
                              ifelse(str_detect(pdd_master$all_causes, "T37")==T,1,
                              ifelse(str_detect(pdd_master$all_causes, "T38")==T,1,
                              ifelse(str_detect(pdd_master$all_causes, "T39")==T,1,
                              ifelse(str_detect(pdd_master$all_causes, "T4")==T,1,
                              ifelse(str_detect(pdd_master$all_causes, "T50")==T,1,
                              ifelse(str_detect(pdd_master$all_causes, "T3691")==T,1,0)))))))))
```

Since their version doesn't need to look at characters in the first 2 or 3 positions in addition to characters in the 6th position I figured I needed to do a more traditional loop.

Comment: This may be me not knowing SAS, but what's supposed to happen for this last `if` statement? `if substrn(odiag(i), 1,4) = 'T369' == 1;`

Comment: whoops, while shortening the code I must have accidentally cut off the last part of the line. I fixed it. It basically assigns a value of 1 to "total_drug" if the first 4 characters of the variable is "T369".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr::if_any()`, you can apply your test across multiple columns using [tidyselect syntax](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html). You can also collapse all your tests into one by testing if the beginning substring is in the range `paste0("T", 36:50)`:

```
library(dplyr)

Drug_inj %>% 
  mutate(total_drug = as.integer(
    if_any(
      .cols = odiag1:odiag5, 
      .fns = ~ (substr(.x, 1, 3) %in% paste0("T", 36:50) & substr(.x, 6, 6) == 1) |
        substr(.x, 1, 4) == "T369"
    )
  ))
```

```
   id odiag1 odiag2 odiag3 odiag4 odiag5 total_drug
1   1 T69880 T48900 T15200 T19781 T96201          0
2   2 T17160 T57341 T77861 T11291 T54481          0
3   3 T58691 T23971 T98041 T70501 T44780          0
4   4 T19430 T69631 T86840 T94860 T21231          0
5   5 T90850 T73650 T59201 T27471 T24791          0
6   6 T36911 T57890 T20900 T33501 T78321          1
7   7 T94121 T43891 T54210 T83670 T73520          1
8   8 T53430 T93100 T71920 T40301 T29870          1
9   9 T71301 T75980 T83571 T66510 T73021          0
10 10 T85040 T42281 T31631 T82660 T98990          1
11 11 T80390 T66010 T91921 T61350 T68470          0
12 12 T69930 T24641 T91030 T82221 T43860          0
13 13 T85660 T39360 T54991 T28981 T64351          0
14 14 T99820 T88390 T88320 T65480 T17440          0
15 15 T40760 T36190 T44520 T27561 T99881          0
16 16 T28401 T69920 T97600 T75070 T42180          0
17 17 T66851 T55650 T28491 T45501 T97011          1
18 18 T88631 T27251 T37961 T67121 T57060          1
19 19 T30791 T57310 T88331 T79461 T37131          1
20 20 T62440 T81541 T65160 T68280 T41260          0
```

*Example data:*

```
set.seed(13)

Drug_inj <- data.frame(id = 1:20)

for (i in 1:5) {
  Drug_inj[[paste0("odiag", i)]] <- paste0(
    "T", 
    sample(1000:9999, 20), 
    sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE)
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the code is doing?

Comment: Sure. The `if_any()` call tests whether any of the columns from `odiag1` through `odiag5` (i.e., `.cols = odiag1:odiag5`) either (1) have first three characters in the range `"T36"` through `"T50"` and a sixth character of `1`, or (2) have first four characters equal to `"T369"`. The `.fns` argument includes the test to be applied, in the form of an anonymous function. It returns a vector that's `TRUE` if the condition is satisfied within any tested column for that row, and `FALSE` otherwise. These logical values are coerced to `1`s and `0`s by `as.integer()`.